# Inserting into middle of a string using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm trying to insert a string into multiple lines using sed, but i don't get the desired result

I have this:

```
<p begin="540960420t" end="600189590t" xml:id="subtitle8">-Some text.<br/>-Some more text</p>
<p begin="601020420t" end="653572920t" xml:id="subtitle9">-Something else<br/>Some more text</p>
<p begin="654403750t" end="731560830t" xml:id="subtitle10">More words<br/>-more text</p>
<p begin="732401670t" end="786625840t" xml:id="subtitle11">Some text.<br/>Some more text</p>
```

and I need to insert this

```
<span style="style0">
```

Before the "subtitle[0-200]"> so it will be like this:

```
<p begin="540960420t" end="600189590t" xml:id="subtitle8"><span style="style0">-Some text.<br/>-Some more text</p>
<p begin="601020420t" end="653572920t" xml:id="subtitle9"><span style="style0">-Some text.<br/>Some more text</p>
```

etc...

I was trying something like this:

```
cat demo.xml | sed 's/xml:id="subtitle[0-9]">/<span style="style0"><p/g'
```

But this **replaces** the xml:id="subtitle[0-9]"> and only from subtitle0 to subtile9

I am quite new to all this sed and regexp thing, if something else should be easier than sed then it's fine ..

Best Regards
Soren

Comment: Before or after?

Comment: Are the blank lines actually part of your input file? Are all lines in that format or should some lines be ignored?

Comment: No, there are no blank lines, I just made those blank line for better overview, should have mentioned that. No lines should be ignored.

Comment: Where do you close that span tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed 's/subtitle[0-9]\{1,3\}">/&<span style="style0">/'
```

This matches the subtitle[0-200] by matching 1 to 3 digits using the `\{1,3\}` and replaces this with the matched pattern with the `<span style...` added.

If you input:

```
<p begin="540960420t" end="600189590t" xml:id="subtitle8">-Some text.<br/>-Some more text</p>

<p begin="601020420t" end="653572920t" xml:id="subtitle9">-Something else<br/>Some more text</p>

<p begin="654403750t" end="731560830t" xml:id="subtitle10">More words<br/>-more text</p>

<p begin="732401670t" end="786625840t" xml:id="subtitle11">Some text.<br/>Some more text</p>
```

This will output

```
<p begin="540960420t" end="600189590t" xml:id="subtitle8"><span style="style0">-Some text.<br/>-Some more text</p>

<p begin="601020420t" end="653572920t" xml:id="subtitle9"><span style="style0">-Something else<br/>Some more text</p>

<p begin="654403750t" end="731560830t" xml:id="subtitle10"><span style="style0">More words<br/>-more text</p>

<p begin="732401670t" end="786625840t" xml:id="subtitle11"><span style="style0">Some text.<br/>Some more text</p>
```

Comment: Replace `\{1,3\}` with `+` to get `sed 's/subtitle[0-9]+">/&<span style="style0">/'` unless it is important for it to go wrong with numbers of more than 3 digits. `+` means one or more of the previous thing.

Comment: I think + is ERE which isn't supported by POSIX sed

Comment: you are correct, you need to use `\+`.

Comment: I found out that this sed 's/subtitle[0-9]\{1,3\}">/&<span style="style0">/' was the best one for me.

Answer (score 1):

If all your lines are as you show, all you need to do is enter the new string after the first `>` on each line:

```
$ sed 's/>/><span style="style0">/' file 
<p begin="540960420t" end="600189590t" xml:id="subtitle8"><span style="style0">-Some text.<br/>-Some more text</p>

<p begin="601020420t" end="653572920t" xml:id="subtitle9"><span style="style0">-Something else<br/>Some more text</p>

<p begin="654403750t" end="731560830t" xml:id="subtitle10"><span style="style0">More words<br/>-more text</p>

<p begin="732401670t" end="786625840t" xml:id="subtitle11"><span style="style0">Some text.<br/>Some more text</p>
```

Comment: I can see that this one will add <span style="style0"> after the <br/> also.

Comment: @SH1986 no,  it only replaces the first `>` not all. You need the `g` flag to replace more.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth man. I had to look twice at it because I was trying to look for some occurrence shortcut at first, but it was very soon apparent that the problem was how to insert a second <...> after the first <...>.